# Hibernate update with default value

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, default-value

after some research i haven't found a solution.
I need a query like this in Hibernate:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field=DEFAULT
```

it's possible to instruct hibernate to generate that query when I need to generate database default value on an update?

I have already try setting insert="false" and update="false", but this work only for insert query, when I perform an update simply hibernate doesn't set the field annotated with update="false".

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some much better sequence to get to the default value but I'm rusty on Hibernate.

```
PersistentClass pClass 
    = configuration.getClassMapping(yourJavaClass.class.getName());
Column col = pClass.getTable(getColumn("Column Name in Table"));
```

Now you can use col.getDefaultValue() and replace nulls with it.

Comment: this solution only work if there is a default value in the hibernate mappings. It's right? If yes this isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. You can certainly use JDBC to get the column default value _from the db_. I thought that is what happens here, but maybe not.